# Display a list of labels in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, python, flask, chart.js, grouped-bar-chart

I have a problem with the graphics of CHART.JS
when trying to get my data from python to pass my list of values as labels in my chartjs grouped bar chart , my list of values is considered as one variable , not all variables of the list are considered as labels !

app.py

```
df= pd.read_excel("Extract_data_eurecia.xlsx") def sum_nbr_heure(id_client,start=0,ends=0): if start == 0 : start = df["Date de l'activité"].min() if ends== 0: ends=df["Date de l'activité"].max() cond=(df["Date de l'activité"]>=start) & (df["Date de l'activité"]<=ends) data=df.loc[cond] return sum(data[data["Clients"]==id_client]["Nb heures"]) def sum_nbr_heure_col(id_client,start=0,ends=0): if(start == 0 ): start = df["Date de l'activité"].min() if ends== 0: ends=df["Date de l'activité"].max() cond=(df["Date de l'activité"]>=start) & (df["Date de l'activité"]<=ends) data=df.loc[cond] a=sum_nbr_heure(id_client,start,ends) return data.loc[data["Clients"]==id_client].groupby(['collaborateur'],as_index=False).agg( sum_hours=('Nb heures', sum), percentage_hours=('Nb heures', lambda x: round(((sum(x) * 100 )/a) ,2)))

def suivi_activite(id_client,start=0,ends=0): if start == 0 : start = df["Date de l'activité"].min() if ends== 0: ends=df["Date de l'activité"].max() cond=(df["Date de l'activité"]>=start) & (df["Date de l'activité"]<=ends) data=df.loc[cond] a=sum_nbr_heure_col(id_client,start,ends) return data.loc[data["Clients"]==id_client].groupby(["Description de la feuille de temps","collaborateur"],as_index=False).agg(sum_hours=('Nb heures', sum))

app = Flask(name)

@app.route('/') def dashboard(): tot_sum_h_per_col=[] tot_sum_h_per_col.append(sum_nbr_heure_col(1949635)['collaborateur'].to_list()) tot_sum_h_per_col.append( sum_nbr_heure_col(1949635)['percentage_hours'].to_list()) dsh_suivi_activite=[] dsh_suivi_activite.append(suivi_activite(1949635)["Description de la feuille de temps"].astype(str).to_list()) dsh_suivi_activite.append(suivi_activite(1949635)["collaborateur"].to_list()) dsh_suivi_activite.append(suivi_activite(1949635)["sum_hours"].to_list()) # dsh_suivi_activite=suivi_activite(1949635) return render_template("chart.html", labs_tot_sum_h_per_col = tot_sum_h_per_col[0], vals_tot_sum_h_per_col=tot_sum_h_per_col[1], #  dsh_suivi_activite=dsh_suivi_activite.to_json() labs_dsh_suivi_activite=dsh_suivi_activite[0], data_labs_dsh_suivi_activite=dsh_suivi_activite[1], data_vals_dsh_suivi_activite=dsh_suivi_activite[2] )

if name == "main": app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

chart.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <!-- <canvas id="myChart" style="width: 100%; max-width: 700px;"></canvas> -->
  <canvas id="pie-chart" width="700" height="500"></canvas>
<script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("pie-chart"), {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {   
      labels: {{labs_tot_sum_h_per_col}},
      datasets: [{
        label: "%",
        backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
        data: {{vals_tot_sum_h_per_col}}
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 
        "Pourcentage somme d'heures de chaque collaborateur"
      }
    }
});
</script>
<canvas id="bar-chart-grouped" width="90" height="45"></canvas>
<h1> test </h1>
<script>

  new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-grouped"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      // labels: {{labs_dsh_suivi_activite}} ,
      labels: ["2022 Semaine 05","2022 Semaine 06","2022 Semaine 06","2022 Semaine 06","2022 Semaine 07","2022 Semaine 07","2022 Semaine 07","2022 Semaine 07","2022 Semaine 08","2022 Semaine 08","2022 Semaine 08","2021 Semaine 46","2021 Semaine 47","2021 Semaine 50"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: {{data_labs_dsh_suivi_activite}},
          data: {{data_vals_dsh_suivi_activite}}
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Suivi d\'activite' 
      }
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]